# Program sessions in Windows

Tags: windows

I'm looking for a program for Windows that would behave analogically to this Google Chrome extensions: https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/bbcnbpafconjjigibnhbfmmgdbbkcjfi with the difference that it would work with programs rather than tabs in a browser.

The Google Chrome extension can save group of tabs and then you can open it and continue with work. Therefore you can work on several projects and you don't need to bother with opening the tabs again.

I'm looking for a program for Windows that can do the similar thing with programs in taskbar - I'm working on several projects and always I need a set of programs to be run in order to be able to work:

e.g.:

1) MS Visual Studio and Browser for reading specs

2) NetBeans and wamp for creating websites

3) ...

It's always the same set of programs that I need at the moment and I'm quite bored of opening them one by one. I don't open all the programs because the taskbar gets really messy.

**Note:** Hibernation of a group of programs would be also great but I guess it would be hard to create such a program.

**Note:** I guess that multiple screens as you can have in Linux would partially solve the problem.

Is there a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Windows Pager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/windowspager/) seems to fit the bill quite well.

> WindowsPager is a pager utility for the Windows XP/Vista Desktop. It fit smoothly into the Desktop panel. WindowsPager provide unlimited support for so called 'virtual desktops' or 'workspaces'.

Just assigned all related programs to a single virtual desktop and activate it as needed.